# Is there a convention for the order of applying ssreflect tactic/taticals?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ssreflect

I am trying to understand how combined ssreflect tactics should be "decomposed" (or how they are composed in the first place). One of the problems I have is to understand the order and associativity of the taticals.

Sometimes, I feel that the order is from right to left. For example

```
apply : AiB.
```

seems equivalent to

```
move : AiB; apply.
```

Ignoring the no-op `move`, it's as if we are applying functions to `AiB` in order, and `apply : AiB.` can be viewed as  `apply (: AiB).` . That is, we first move AiB into the goal and then call `apply` on the goal with `AiB` in it.

However, I am confused in other occasions:

```
case: (EM (P y)) => // notPy.
```

According to the [tutorial](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00407778/file/RT-367.pdf), this one does a case analysis on `(EM (P y))`, and then `//` tries to solve trivial sub-goals. Then?? `move =>` introduce the remaining ones into the context? What's the order of operations here?

Let `EM_` be `(EM (P y))`, is it `(move=> notPy (// ( case (:EM_) ) ) )` ??
Am I reading this right, what is the "correct order" of tactic application?

The order is kind of **twisted** near `notPy` and inconsistent in general. Is there a way to write the above *from right to left* in legitimate ssreflect?

Answer (score 2):

I advice you read the manual to get more details. https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00258384

In your example, recall that move is always a no-op, so it "fuses". Thus with colon, it fuses on the left.

```
move: H; case <=> case: H
```

and with `=>` it fuses on the right:

```
case: H; move => U <=> case: H => U.
```

Thus for your particular example,

```
case: (EM (P y)) => // notPy.
```

could be seen as

```
move: (EM (P y)); case; move=> // notPy.
```

Regards!